# A module to profile peak memory usage of Python code

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, memory-profiling

Currently, I tried to use the memory_profiler module to get the used memory like the following code:

```
from memory_profiler import memory_usage
memories=[]
def get_memory(mem,ended):
  if ended:
    highest_mem=max(mem)
    print highest_mem
  else:
  memories.append(mem)

def f1():
  #do something
  ended=False
  get_memory(memory_usage(),ended)
  return #something
def f2():
  #do something
  ended=False
  get_memory(memory_usage(),ended)
  return #something

#main
f1()
f2()
ended=True
get_memory(memory_usage(),ended) #code end

>>>#output
# output 
# highest memory
```

however, it did not successfully execute. It got stuck when ended=True and sent the value of memory_usage() and ended to the function of get_memory. It did not show any error as well., just waiting for long long time, then I force to stop executing. Anyone knows the better way or the solution?

Comment: What was the output exactly?

Comment: Also is there some reason you're not just using the decorators or the default profiler report? The use of the lower level api just seems to complicate things in your case and you're not really doing anything with it.

Comment: I would change the title of the question, since what is "the best" is primarly opinion based, which is a reason to close question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An easy way to use `memory_usage` to get the peak / maximum memory from a block of code is to first put that code in a function, and then pass that function - without the () call - to `memory_usage()` as the `proc` argument:

```py
from memory_profiler import memory_usage

def myfunc():
  # code
  return
    
mem = max(memory_usage(proc=myfunc))

print("Maximum memory used: {} MiB".format(mem))
```

Other arguments allow you to collect timestamps, return values, pass arguments to `myfunc`, etc. The docstring seems to be the only complete source for documentation on this: https://github.com/fabianp/memory_profiler/blob/master/memory_profiler.py

https://github.com/fabianp/memory_profiler/blob/4089e3ed4d5c4197925a2df8393d4cbfca745ae5/memory_profiler.py#L244

Answer (score 0):

I mainly use **[Heapy](http://guppy-pe.sourceforge.net/#Heapy)** because it's really easy to use.

Just type the following code where you want to test for memory usage.

```
from guppy import hpy
hp = hpy()
print hp.heap()
```